# Trinity Wallet and Ledger Nano X how to restore the private key without a ledger nano

Tags: hardware-wallet

i have a question about the Trinity-Wallet in combination with Ledger Nano X.
If i store my seed on the ledger nano and it gets lost i can restore my seed with a new ledger nano and the 24-word recovery phrase.
see therefore:

> https://trinity.iota.org/hardware/ --> Ledger FAQs
>
> I lost my Ledger device, what should I do now?
>
> Hopefully you backed up your 24-word recovery phrase (and optional passphrase) in a safe place. Otherwise your funds are lost.
> If you did back-up your recovery phrase, you can buy a new Ledger Nano S and enter the recovery phrase (and optional passphrase) when setting up the new device.
> Simply install the IOTA Ledger app,and set up your device with Trinity to access your funds again.

But what if i have no new Ledger device, how can i restore my iota with the 24-word recovery phrase only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first some warnings:

- Never give your seed or your recovery phrase to anyone! They will steal all your cryptocurrency token / money! We will never ask you for this information!
- Take care, because if you use it, the seed gets exposed outside of the Ledger device, which defies the purpose of having a hardware wallet at all.

muXxer a valuable IOTA Community member wrote a script to restore your seed that you can find here:

https://github.com/IOTA-Ledger/recover-iota-seed-from-ledger-mnemonics

Source:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Iota/comments/9tlmrj/can_i_restore_my_iota_seed_from_my_ledger_backup/

another valuable IOTA Community member, Mobilefish, made a video tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfXuWhl1SZs

Be aware that I did not test this and these are community projects and we can give no guarantee that they work.